# Scrolling just one (z-index) layer

Tags: javascript, overflow, z-index

I have a link "ABOUT", when I click on it, it will appear some infos (z-index: 100) that cover the main page. (Once that button is clicked it becomes "CLOSE" thanks to a javascript I found somewhere)

How can I say to that ABOUT button, once clicked, to add to the body the overflow:hidden tag so when I scroll the infos the main page remain where it is? (And I guess I should say to the "CLOSE" button to add back the ovewflow:auto to the body)

MMM not sure it's that clear but this is the best I can do in english.

Thanks for any help.
Fed.

Comment: provide a code sample.. use **stub** functions to indicate what you're attempting to do.

Comment: the real question is, why are your trying to achieve this.. what's the real issue you're having? and by `body`.. are you referring to `document.body`. or do you mean the container of whatever 'popup' the about button invokes?

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.overflow = "hidden";
```

Comment: is there something wrong with just doing `document.body`?

Comment: Was that what you were looking for ??

Comment: I want to do that to the document.body cause I'd love the photos there to remain static while scrolling the infos. It's hard to provide a fiddle but you can see what I mean here: http://www.thisisfed.com

Answer (score 0):

From what I can determine of your question.. this seems to be what you're attempting to do.

Add a click event to an element that toggles the `document.body.style.overflow` in order to suppress the scrolling behavior.

```js
function ToggleBodyOverflow(ev)
{
    if (document.body.style.overflow !== "hidden")
    {   
        document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "whitesmoke";
    } else {    
        document.body.style.overflow = "auto";
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "gray";
    }
}

document.getElementById("btnBodyToggle").addEventListener("click",ToggleBodyOverflow);
```

```css
body {display:inline;width:100%;height:100%;position:relative; background-color:green;}
div#cover {display:block;background-color:gray;height:2500px; width:2700px;}
```

```html
<button id="btnBodyToggle">Toggle Document.Body Overflow</button>
<div id="cover"></div>
```

### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aszwgkw3/

---

Note, I'm not sure how effective this will be in practice.. if you click and hold the middle button on your mouse, it commonly breaks the overlay hidden behavior.. mobile device scrolling/dragging might pose an issue as well.

Comment: note.. I have no idea how (or whether) the zIndex aspect of your question title is relevant.